# ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 58 layers into a model with 55 layers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I trained my model and saved the model in .h5 format. Trained by freezing the last layer of the mobilenet imagenet model. 
Loading the model and trying prediction makes error stating ***ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 58 layers into a model with 55 layers.***

Training code :

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# In[2]:


base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False) #imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #we add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for better results.
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
preds=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation


# In[3]:


model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)
#specify the inputs
#specify the outputs
#now a model has been created based on our architecture


# In[4]:


for layer in model.layers[:20]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[20:]:
    layer.trainable=True


# In[5]:


train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) #included in our dependencies

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./train/', # this is where you specify the path to the main data folder
                                                 target_size=(224,224),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=64,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=True)


# In[33]:


model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
# Adam optimizer
# loss function will be categorical cross entropy
# evaluation metric will be accuracy

step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   epochs=10)

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("mobilenet_2.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("mobilenet_2.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Prediciton code :

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications import MobileNet
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("mobilenet_1.h5")
#mobile = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(weights="imagenet")
def prepare_image(file):
    img_path = ''
    img = image.load_img("/home/christie/mobilenet/transfer-learning/" + file, target_size=(224, 224))
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array_expanded_dims = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    return keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input(img_array_expanded_dims)
'''
lookup_list = ["banana","banana_palenkodan","banana_red","banana_nendran","banana_karpooravalli"]
        #print(lookup_list)

    if ans not in lookup_list:sx
        print("Not found")
        return "[None]"
'''

preprocessed_image = prepare_image('test.jpg')
predictions = model.predict(preprocessed_image)
results = imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(predictions)
print(results)
```

Error log :

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 58 layers
>   into a model with 55 layers.

Answer (score 1):

The model is converted to JSON format and written to mobilenet_2.json in the local directory. The network weights are written to mobilenet_2.h5 in the local directory.

Similarly you have to load the json and its corresponding weights.

Try editing as below :

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("mobilenet_2.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("mobilenet_2.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# later...

# load json and create model
json_file = open('mobilenet_2.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("mobilenet_2.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

You are saving just the weights but trying to load the model architecture and weights. If you would like to save weights and model architecture together and later load, then try the below code -

```
# save model and architecture to single file
model.save("model.h5")

# later...

# load model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: @Sai Krishnadas - If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote the answer. Thank You.